# Why application is in container creation state using rancher/rke on Centos and OpenEBS?

Tags: openebs

Application is in container creation state. Also I have followed the per-requisites that iSCSI has to be installed on host node.I have a setup using rancher/rke with bare-metal hosts running CentOS. I tried to deploy Percona application and I can see my OpenEBS replica pods and Controller Pods are running fine but not Percona.

Answer (score 0):

If iSCSI has installed in both kubelet container and host, then this issue will come. To solve this, you need to un-install iSCSI from host.